# How to wrap soucecode in Storybook mdx file

Tags: reactjs, storybook, pre

In my Storybook docs I am trying to display source code in a `div`, primarily to show it in a grid. So I would like to do something like:

````
<div>
  ```tsx dark
  return 'source code here' ```
</div>
````

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out all I needed to do was:

````
<div>

  ```tsx dark
  return 'source code here' ```

</div>
````